# WinSCP with sk-ed25519 Key

Tags: windows, ssh, winscp

Since pageant cannot work with security keys / sk-ed25519, i moved over to OpenSSHs agent on Windows. Generating and importing sk-ed25519 is no problem. use these keys for open ssh sessions also works great.

i do not find a way to support these keys in Winscp.
Is it possible or are there alternatives to winscp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SK SSH Agent](https://github.com/tetractic/SK-SSH-Agent) supports security keys and WinSCP.